# What's the best way to clear session files for a cherrypy app on RHEL 6 without clearing active sessions?

Tags: session, cherrypy, rhel6

What's the best way to clear session files for a cherrypy app on RHEL 6.3 without clearing active sessions?  Can I run a cron job that clears files where the last modified is greater than 15 days old?

I've tried executing this command...

```
find /path/to/files* -mtime +5 -exec rm {} \;
```

from [this site](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/delete-files-older-than-x-days-on-linux/)

But it doesn't remove any files modified at least 5 days ago.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sessions in cherrypy are expired and removed given the parameters of the session:

- timeout: specify the minutes of inactivity to mark it as expired.
- clean_freq: specify the frequency of the session cleaning in minutes

For example to dispatch a thread to delete the files each 3 minutes and a timeout of 5 minutes then just configure the session like this:

```
{'tools.sessions.timeout': 5,
 'tools.sessions.clean_freq': 3}
```

For more information on the properties of the session check out [the official documentation.](http://cherrypy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/refman/lib/sessions.html#cherrypy.lib.sessions.init)

But if you are looking to execute the cleaning by a cronjob why not just specify +4 instead of +5 to include the 5 on the date range, like:

```
find /path/to/files* -mtime +4 -exec rm {} \;
```

Comment: Well I'm actually having problems with bots that don't except cookies.  Cherrypy is not cleaning those up.  I'll try your cronjob command and see if that cleans up old session files.